# Eclipse indexer not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to set up PCL with eclipse. I have never did any CMake stuff, so I don't really know what is going on.

I have installed PCL with `apt-get`. Next, I made folder `~/hello_pcl/src`, where I saved `pcd_write.cpp` file and following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(hello_pcl)
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable (pcd_write_exe pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcd_write_exe ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Next, I've done:

```
cd ~/hello_pcl
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../src
```

As for the last, I have imported created project into eclipse with *File* -> *Import* -> *C/C++* -> *Existing code as Makefile project*.

My problem is: after that, the application runs correctly, but Eclipse code editor marks all includes as `Unresolved inclusion` and almost every function as `Unresolved symbol`. Strangely, it does it also with `#include <iostream>`. I figured out, that it's a problem with indexer. Therefore, I have add `/usr/include/c++/4.8` and `/usr/include/pcl-1.7` in *Project properties* -> *C/C++ general* -> *Paths and symbols* in *Includes* tab and *GCC C++* language.
It seems to have resolved some of the issues, but there are still functions, that are marked red (see screenshot).

[image: indexer_error]

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It seems, that in this case, typicas workflow for using Eclipse CDT with CMake makes indexer work incorectly.

What I have done is, after invoking `cmake` command, imported project not as *Makefile project*, but with *Import* -> *General* -> *Existing projects into workspace*.

After importing project in this way, indexer takes really lot of time (and I suppose it can crush Eclipse, if project is big enough) to parse all includes. But after that everything works fine.